# datatype for storing timezones

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, timezone, timezone-offset

I want to store timezones but not in the timezoneoffset datatype. Should I use a decimal or a float? Or something else? Timezones can be GMT -3.5 for NewFoundland or +5.5 for parts of India so int wouldn't work.

Comment: What about timezones like "America/Vancouver"? DST adjustments (when it occurs and if it exists at all) depend on politics so there is a good argument for using the city based timezones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a lookup table?  It would look like this:

```
create table TimeZone (
    id int identity primary key,
    name varchar(50),
    offset decimal(2,1)
)
```

With a foreign key reference from your main table.

Comment: What if I just want to select a datatype? What's the datatype to choose in SQL server?

Comment: In my case, you would use an int, and make it a foreign key that references the table above.  Other than datetimeoffset, your only other option would be a decimal or numeric column.  I would tend towards the separate table approach, as you could use it to drive a drop-down in the UI, and it would make for better reporting.

Comment: IF I go with a decimal, what should I use? Decimal(4,2)?

Comment: I would say 3,1.  Check the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx) for the `decimal` data type for more information.

Comment: One decimal position might [be](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%2B05:45) [not](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%2B08:45) [enough](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%2B12:45).